# emberjs - Control when an initializer is ran

Tags: ember.js

I have some code that raises a basic pubsub event:

```
export default Ember.Service.extend(ConnectListenersMixin, {
  onGetInitial: function() {
    this.trigger('listUpdated', payload);
}
```

This request that ends up triggering the event is made from the `beforeModel` hook of a route:

```
  beforeModel: function() {
    this.TodoActions.getTodos();
  }
```

The problem is that the code that subscribes to this event is made in the `init` event of a component:

```
export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  connect: Ember.on('init', function(){
    // subscribing code
  })
});
```

When the application is first loaded the event is triggered before the subscribing code has ran.  After the component is initialised, then all is good.

Is there any way that I can initialize the components earlier so that they are all subscribed before the event is raised?

I'm not sure what events are available from initializers, the only one that I am aware of is `registerComponentLookup`, e.g.

`before: 'registerComponentLookup'`

Is there anyway round this?

I'm experimenting with not using proimises and not using the model hook so please don't suggest that.  I know all about that.

Answer (score 0):

Components are instantiated when Ember sees that they need to instantiated.  If the component is instantiated from a Handlebars template, then this is naturally after the model hooks and there's nothing you can do about that.  The template won't even render until the model hooks are finished, in fact.

I would take a look at doing the subscription from the controller and either have it emit events, trigger events on the components, or simply store the data so the component can bind to it.  I don't have enough information about your use case to say which (or if any) is best, however.